# Marionette ItemView events after re-rendering

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

i'm playing with Marionette first time. 
After re-rendering ItemViews, their events not triggered.
Simple example:

```
App = new Marionette.Application;

App.addRegions({
    headerRegion: '#header',
    contentRegion: '#content',
});

App.addInitializer(function () {
    this.Views = {
        MainMenu : new MainMenuView(),
        ContentOne : new ContentOneView(),
        ContentTwo : new ContentTwoView(),
    };
});

App.addInitializer(function () {
    var self = this;
    var eva = self.vent;
    eva.listenTo(self.Views.MainMenu, 'content1', function () {
        self.contentRegion.show(self.Views.ContentOne);
    });
    eva.listenTo(self.Views.MainMenu, 'content2', function () {
        self.contentRegion.show(self.Views.ContentTwo);
    });
});

App.on('start', function () {
    var self = this;
    self.contentRegion.show(self.View.ContentOne);
});

App.start();
```

After re-rendering ContentOneView & ContentTwoView, their events not triggered.
What i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 5):

The problem you are having is that `region.show()` is going to close any view that is currently occupying that region. Doing so undelegates the view's events. After the initial `region.show()` you should manually call render on the view.

You can see [this explained here](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.region.md#basic-use) and an issue [discussing it here](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/pull/654).

Comment: I've tried to use `self.View.ContentOne.render()` instead `self.contentRegion.show(self.View.ContentOne)`, but nothing happiens.

Comment: example: each ContentView has a button within itself, and event for this button. First time all events triggered normally, but second time, after re-rendering, events for buttons not triggered.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to solve this problem by using delegating the events when the view is shown in the layout:

```
layoutView.content.show(contentView);
contentView.delegateEvents();
```

Although this is only necessary after the first render as mentioned by Andrew Hubbs

Answer (score 1):

instead of using eva to listen to events that happen on the views, try listening to eva for events passed by other views

```
App.addInitializer(function () {
    var eva = self.vent;
    var self = this;
    this.listenTo(eva, 'someStringHere', function(){/*do stuff here*/};
});
```

and then in your views you can trigger events through eva/vent

```
var eva = self.vent;
eva.trigger("someStringHere");
```